# A reference containing computational examples for Quantum information

Tags: reference-request, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information

I need a reference, book, lecture note, webpage, or whatever containing a lot of computed examples. What I need is not just something having definitions, statement, proof. I don't need any statement-proof boring book as I have a large amount of them inside! I just need something having examples of computing Choi-Jamilkowski isomorphism, Stinespring dilation, Kraus operator sum representations with calculations to give a feeling that when someone give us an arbitrary CPTP map, I can compute these for it. Saying this uses that and that uses that ... is just making you willingless to continue the story. Examples and being able to compute is what will give you happy feeling and imagination.